# Titanium mobile image processing

Tags: javascript, image, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have an image view, and after getting the image and setting the image view I am having a simple problem.

Depending on if it is landscape or portrait, and if the image view is a square, the image view will not be filled. The only way I can achieve this using a landscape photo is to essentially crop it, otherwise it is stretched.

The trouble is - by cropping the photo into a square that I can then resize - I end up losing the areas that I have cropped, making way for an incomplete photo.

Alternatively, I could force the image to fill the view, but it will end up being stretched in the process.

Is there anyway to achieve this? I have already looked at imagefactory, but haven't had much luck.

Thanks

Comment: So you want the square `ImageView` to be filled with the non-square `Image`, but don't want it to be cropped?...

Comment: I have seen some apps where this has been possible, I assume that once they get the image cropping/rescaling is done to turn it into a square without losing any detail?

Comment: a better question to ask, what is the best way to set image views based on the idea of profile pics in an app? Should I get them to crop it into a square first?

Comment: thanks guys I got it to work. Unfortunantly, you have to crop and resize it. Then use x and y properties to position the image in a view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes a method for making an imageView exactly of image so it does not get crop or blur.You have to use a temporary image for this purpose

```
var imageTemp = Ti.UI.createImageView({
  image : someFile.read(),
  height:'auto',
  width:'auto'
});
Ti.API.info( "height=" + imageTemp.size.height);
Ti.API.info( "width=" + imageTemp.size.width);
imageTemp = null;
```

Thanks